# Создание и использование собственной динамической библиотеки в Qt c++

Tags: c++, qt, unix, lib

Всем привет.
Перед мной стоит задача в написании собственной динамической библиотеки в Qt. Прочитал данную статью https://habr.com/ru/post/101994/. Сделал всё как там сказано. Библиотека билдится всё ок. Теперь я имею 3 файла TestDinamicLib (это название моей тестовой либы) в ней содержатся такие файлы TestDinamicLib.cpp, TestDinamicLib.h, TestDinamicLib.pro, TestDinamicLib.user, TestDinamicLib_global.h.
И два файла build-TestDinamicLib-Desktop_Qt_5_12_2_GCC_64bit-Debug и Release. (Думаю понимаете что в них). Код писался в ununtu, qt 5.12.
У меня вопрос как подключить данну библиотеку к новому проекту.
Заранее всем спасибо.
.pro

```
    QT -= gui
    
    TEMPLATE = lib
    DEFINES += dist
    
    VERSION = 1.0.0
    
    TARGET = $$qtLibraryTarget(TestDinamicLib)
    
    CONFIG += build_all
    
    DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
    
    SOURCES += \
        testdinamiclib.cpp
    
    HEADERS += \
        TestDinamicLib_global.h \
        testdinamiclib.h
    
    DEFINES += TestDinamicLib_LIBRARY
    
    # Default rules for deployment.
    unix {
        target.path = /usr/lib
    }
    !isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
    
    unix: {
           CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
           TARGET = ComputerManagerd
           } else {
                   TARGET = ComputerManager
           }
    
    } else {
            TARGET = $$qtLibraryTarget(ComputerManager)
    
    }
    
    VERSION = 1.0.0
    
    CONFIG (debug, debug|release) {
            OBJECTS_DIR = build/debug
    } else {
            OBJECTS_DIR = build/release
    }
```

Comment: Отформатируйте код

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.pro-файл проекта, к которому надо подключить либу:

```
#Путь к заголовочным файлам либы
INCLUDEPATH += /path/to/the/libs_headers/

#путь к самой либе и сама либа
LIBS += -Lpath/to/the/lib/ -lname_of_the_lib
```

name_of_the_lib (у вас может быть другое имя) это имя библиотеки без префикса lib и расширения .a, или .so. То есть полное имя на диске будет выглядеть так `libname_of_the_lib.a`, а указываете как показано в примере